# Cannot copy MP3 files from a CD

Tags: mount, cd, cd-drive

I purchased a set of spoken word audio CD's that have MP3 and FLAC audio files; I think they also play as regular audio CD's because  I see a CDA directory and .cda files. But I'm only interested in playing the MP3 files by copying them to my phone.

Dolphin file manager shows all the files on the CD. However, it will not copy any of them to my hard drive, which is what my goal is. Dolphin shows no error, but the copy progress is zero.

Amarok *will* play the files but not easily. I only tried the flac files. To play a file, I click the file in Dolphin, then I have to cancel a job using KDE's notification system, then Amarok proceeds to copy the file to a tmp directory which takes a long time, then it finally plays.

kb3 will rip the audio, but I would prefer to copy the files directly from the CD.

Since Dolphin would not copy the files, I thought I would try the terminal, but I can't get that to work either.

```
mount -t auto -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/temp
```

that gives the error:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, etc.
```

I get the same error using `-t iso9660` and `-t udf`.

so I started troubleshooting:

```
~$ wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'MATSHITA' 'DVD-RAM UJ8A0AS'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/sg1 is not a block device

sudo file -s /dev/sr0
ERROR: cannot read /dev/sr0 (input/output error)

sudo file -s /dev/sg1 just hangs
```

How can I copy these files to my computer hard disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wodim says: you can't.
It has no real filesystem (it is not a block device) so you will have to rip it.

Comment: sometimes the files actually do copy, although very slowly. So I'm not fully satisfied with "you can't".

Comment: Technically you are right but ripping is exactly that: copying from a device without filesystem. Not every system is "smart" enough to handle that via copy and it is also very error prone. in other words: Don't copy from such a device if you can rip it.